# mysql group to columns

Tags: php, mysql

So i have to columns in my table one called spend and one save.

what I would like to do is join the two so that is says offers and has the spend|save

Say I have table as

```
spend    save
30       10
```

Output I want is

```
spend    save   dummyCol
30       10     30|10
```

Comment: select spend,save from your_table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you just want to concatenate them? Use [`CONCAT_WS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) to concatenate with a pipe separator:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('|', spend, save) AS spendsave FROM tbl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below

`SELECT spend, save, CONCAT(spend, '|', save) as dummyCol from myTable;`

Here is [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) with more details.. Look for `CONCAT`.

Also look for `CONCAT_WS`. It is useful when you want to add SAME thing at many places...

### Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT `spend`, `save`, CONCAT(`spend`, '|', `save`) as dummyCol 
FROM   `myTable`
```